Lua/Roblox Studio - How do I hide a scrolling frame
I am new to here, I'm also a beginner in Lua. I know something about Roblox Studio though. But how do I hide a scrolling frame with a button as the frame's child? I've made some rules by scrolling frame and "I agree" button in it. I want the rules to hide when button is clicked.
I tried
local button = script.Parent
local menu = script.Parent.Parent.Parent

local function onButtonClicked()
    if menu.Visible then
        menu.Visible = false
    else
        menu.Visible = true
    end
end

button.MouseButton1Down:Connect(onButtonClicked)

and it resulted with nothing.

As a quick note, when getting click events from buttons, for combatilbititly between devices you should use the button.Activated event, and use the same syntax, like this: button.Activated:Connect(function() But that's not super important for this post.

If the button is a direct child of the scrolling frame you're going up one parent too much.
It should be this:
local menu = script.Parent.Parent

If that's not it, you might have accidentally disabled your script.
I've recreated your scenario in my own studio and your code works fine, see the images and link to a short video below.
Since your script works just fine for me, it might not work for you because you disabled it. To enable it, right-click the script and select "Enable scripts".
My set-up:
(As per your current code)

See the result here (gyazo).
Hopefully, this resolves your issue.

oh wait im dumb... i didnt even think that can be the problem

Did it help your issue?

yes, sorry for being inactive
